# Getting BeanCreationException on a bean when transaction is used

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, transactions

I have a bean which is basically a service that is made transactional using the `@Transactional` annotation. I'm using hibernate and here is applicationContext.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db"/>
        <property name="user" value="username"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.myprojects.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userService" class="com.myprojects.service">
        <property name="template" ref="hibernateTemplate"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I'm new to spring and hibernate and when I went through the docs of spring transaction management [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html) I tried implementing a simple transaction based bean like the above example but on deploying this, I get beancreationexception. Am I missing any config?

Stack trace:

> Sep 29, 2013 9:25:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
>   SEVERE: Servlet /myWorld threw load() exception
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.myprojects.myworld.daoimpl.UsersDAOImpl] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:986)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:856)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>       at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1213)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1026)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4421)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4734)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:563)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1399)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
>       at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>       at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>       at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1500)
>       at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:670)
>       at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doPut(ManagerServlet.java:435)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

I have a controller where service is autowired:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private service s;

    //few methods like getUser/postUser are written here
}
```

Service:

```
@Transactional
public class service {
    private HibernateTemplate template;
    public void updateUser(User u) {
        Session session = template.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        u.update(session);
    }
}
```

User class:

```
public class User {
    public void updateUser(Session session) {
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        try {
           //carry out update user
        } catch(Exception e) {
           tx.rollback();
        } finally {
           session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Hibernate config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

myproject-servlet.xml :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myprojects"/>

    <context:annotation-config/> 
    <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

</beans>
```

web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfiguration</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myproject</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/myproject-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myproject</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/v1/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: You should post your `BeanCreationException` stack trace. Spring put it there for a reason.

Comment: Could not autowire field: private com.myprojects.service com.myprojects.pojo is the error I'm getting. But I dont understand why it says it is private. When I remove @transactional, it works fine.

Comment: You can edit your question. Post the **full** stacktrace in there.

Comment: Post the complete stacktrace in the question

Comment: Ok, now please post the related classes (those trying to use `@Autowired` and `@Transactional`).

Comment: Your `service` class should be annotated with `@Service`. Please show your full context. It doesn't explain why `service` bean can't be found.

Comment: Why so? I tried but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: It is complaining about the private variable in controller.

Comment: @NullPointerException Yeah got it.

Comment: Do you have a 'service' class defined in your spring config some where?  BTW, it is recommended that class names are capitalized.  From your exception message it looks like there is a problem reading a package...

Comment: Yes I have a "service" class. If I remove @transactional annotation things work fine. So looks like I'm doing something wrong in configuring transaction. But not sure what

Comment: @coder We can only make assumptions until you post your full configuration and the classes involved.

Comment: In the service class I want to make DB queries using hibernate template. And for this, I was trying to open a new session for every request but when I found that this might not be a good idea and using current session would be better, I set hibernate's current_session_context_class to thread and transaction as shown above. But I'm unable to even deploy this application to server.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ok let me post full code.

Comment: @coder Ok, maybe I should have been more clear. We don't need your `User` class or `hibernate` config. We need your **full Spring context**. It would be nice to see your full `service` class as well.

Comment: Service class has just updateUser method. I just wanted to check transactions by running this simple functionality. Hence there is hardly anything in this class

Comment: @coder Please also post your servlet context.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have updated servlet context.

Comment: I ran what you've shown us and everything is autowired fine. Are you sure you don't have some kind of `ClassNotFoundException` that is causing problems higher up in the chain? Please double-check everything and post the full exception log.

Comment: I dont see any ClassNotFoundException. This worked for you? I'm really surprised. I only BeanCreationException in the stack trace. I was actually thinking I might have made some mistake in spring context configuration. The moment I remove @Transactional things work fine.

Comment: Does placing service and userController in 2 different packages matter? I have service in com.myprojects.services pkg and userController in com.myprojects.controllers pkg. But component scan base pkg is com.myprojects in servlet.xml

Comment: I have edited the stack trace. Please take a look and let me know if you find anything.

Comment: You should read about how you should separate the beans declared in your application context and those declared in the servlet context. You don't want to duplicate beans.

Comment: After lot of going back and forth on this, I figured out the root cause. Apparently service was implementing an interface and when I removed it, things started working fine. Why is it unable to find the bean when it is implementing an interface?

Answer (score 1):

Since your `service` is a concrete class (not an Interface), you could add the attribute `proxy-target-class="true"` to `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>`

Either that or create an Interface (of which `service` could be a concrete implementation) and use that Interface for Autowiring/Injection.

Reference: [Spring Transaction Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)

Note that when setting `proxy-target-class="true"`, be sure to keep the `@Transactional` annotation on the concrete class. The above referenced Spring documentation has much more info on that point, and where the `@Transactional` annotation should be put.

Comment: This won't change anything, the problem is when autowiring. There's no `service` bean in the context.

Comment: It doesn't work. It is unable to find the bean when autowiring